# Border Color in #xxxxx-code impossible?

Tags: css, html, border

This is my code:

```
<div style="float: left; height:40px; border-left: 1px solid; border-color:#0c0c0c;">
                        &nbsp;
                        </div>
```

But I get a black border left.
When I insert "Red" instead the #-code, I get a red border.

What I do wrong?

EDIT:I'm not searching color-codes! The color code I will use is #0c0c0c, but when I insert it (like here) it doesn't work, it only show a black border!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#0c0c0c` hexadecimal colour code is a very dark grey. Over a single pixel, depending on the background colour of your page, could well look black.

**Edit:** The rest of my answer was of no use after your edit, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Red code is `#F00`!
Assure you the color code is correct before saying it doesn't work.

EDIT : #0C0C0C is nearly black.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Actually the color code you have used is a very dark grey. So possibly it will look as black for naked eyes. Thats why you are feeling it as black.

Answer (score 0):

Same as Saladin, the #0c0c0c is very similar to black.

Difference is almost invisible.